# Female protagonist is a mage, has a prophecy about her and dies, but is brought back by her soulmate

Tags: story-identification, books, magic

I remember it starts with the characters being in highschool, and the aunt owns a library — her name's Claire, I believe. They're called mages, and they can do magic. There's a character named Conner. The main female character has a prophecy about her, and the bad guys are after her. The book ends with a fight and the main character dies, but Conner brings her back because they're soulmates, and the house explodes. I know the book's by a female author too.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When did you read this?  Do you remember what the cover looked like?

Comment: It was last year and the cover has a silhouette of a girl on it

Comment: The main female character name is rianna or raine something along the lines of that

Answer (score 3):

This was a challenge to find, but I think you might be thinking of the ***The Phrophecized* series, by Kaitlyn Hoyt**.

From the description of the first book, [Blackmoon Beginnings](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/17379473-blackmoon-beginnings):

> Ryanne Arden was on track to being Stormfield High School’s Valedictorian. Being the shy, quiet studious type, she’s always done her own thing. That all changed when a drunk man decided to get behind the wheel of a car. With the death of her mother, Ryanne is suddenly more alone than she’s ever been. With no friends or family to turn to, a local woman named Jane offers to help Ryanne in her time of need.
>
> With graduation looming ahead of her, eighteen year old Ryanne must get her act together if she wants to get out of the small town of Stormfield, Maine and away from her painful memories.
>
> Meeting the attractive Colton Wagner, changes everything. He awakes something in Ryanne that even she didn’t know she had. Magic. With her life suddenly thrown upside down, Ryanne has been thrust into a world completely unbeknown to her.
>
> Being the only non-mage to ever gain magic, paints a target on Ryanne’s back. She’s the girl the whole mage world has been searching for. It has been prophesized for thousands of years that a young non-mage female would put an end to the chaos created by rogue mages, the Gadramicks. Their manipulative leader, Dravin, will do anything within his power to prevent the prophecy from being fulfilled.

However, it's looking at the description for the fourth book, *[Reaching Retribution](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/18715200-reaching-retribution)*, that makes me think this might be what you're looking for:

> It seems as if everything Ryanne does results badly for her or those around her. Her last attempt to save someone’s life ended up killing her. Now stuck in limbo with no idea how to get back to her body, Ryanne is in desperate need of some guidance.
>
> A mage who left her life too soon appears to help guide Ryanne back to her destined path. Not everything is smooth sailing though. Ryanne has a lot of things she has to overcome if she wants to get back.
>
> **Without his soulmate, Colton is lost. Everything crashes down around him when he can’t heal Ryanne. He watched her die again**, and now he wants to get revenge on the Gadramick responsible for putting her life in danger in the first place.
>
> However, a new threat looms just around the corner, and Dravin may not be the only one they have to worry about. Everything is flipped upside down as the prophecy starts unraveling in unforeseen ways.
>
> A battle will ensue. Lives will be lost. A prophecy will unfold before their very eyes. Retribution is coming whether anyone is prepared or not.
> <sub>(emphasis added)</sub>

---

You mention in a comment that "The main female character name is rianna or raine something along the lines of that" - this matches up, with her name being Ryanne. Instead of "Conner" being her soulmate, his name is Colton. There is indeed a prophecy about her, and the bad guys are after her; she "dies" and is presumably returned to her body by Colton, which the description describes as her soulmate. And yes, the series is by a woman.

---

This was found via a Google search for `"mage" soulmates prophecy high school` (after a dozen other failed search attempts).